# Shellscript creating directories in wrong direcroy when running from crontab

Tags: bash, cron

I have written the following code which will create directories with name format "nowt_hour_minute_second". In that directory another text file will be created with the directory creation time. Now I have set the directory creation path as `adhikarisubir@ubuntu:~/test/basic_unix`. when I am manually invoking the script the directories are getting created in the aforementioned directory but when I am running from the crontab it is getting created in `adhikarisubir@ubuntu:~`. Following is my script:

```
 #THIS CODE WILL CREATE A DIRECTORY WITH TIME OF CREATION AS PART OF DIRECTORY NAME
 echo "The time is $(date +%H_%M_%S)"
 now=$(date +%H_%M_%S)
 echo $now
 echo $(pwd) 
 createdep=nowt_$now
 echo "$createdep"
 mkdir "$createdep"
 cd nowt_$now
 echo "Current directory is $(pwd)"
 echo "This is a text file which will contain the createtime" > Newtxt.txt
 sed -i "s/createtime/$(date '+%H:%M:%S')/g" Newtxt.txt
```

My crontab command is:

```
*/2 * * * * sh test/basic_unix/createfiles.sh
```

Comment: crontab runs with limited environment variables; you have to use absolute paths.

Comment: @JacobVlijm, Can you please expand on? Are some more parameters required in the crontab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are in the directory `~/test/basic_unix` and invoke your script, your `mkdir "$createdep"` command creates that folder in `~/test/basic_unix` because that's the current directory, that's where you ran the script from. However, when you run that script from cron, the directory you start with is your home directory, `~`, so your `mkdir` command creates the folder there.

Your confusion might be because you think that since your script is under `~/test/basic_unix/createfiles.sh`, then the folders will always be created there, but that's incorrect. It's not about where the script is located, it's about **where you run** the script from. To give you an example, make a directory `~/testing2`, then `cd ~/testing2`, then call your script using `sh ~/test/basic_unix_createfiles.sh`. You'll find that your folders are being created under `~/testing2`, not `~/test/basic_unix`. Why? Because that's where you ran the script from, and since your `mkdir` command is using a relative path, i.e. since your `mkdir` command is like this: `mkdir foldername`, it creates it in working directory.

To fix your problem, the easiest way is to `cd` to where you want to create the folders at the very beginning, so your script would look like this:

```
#THIS CODE WILL CREATE A DIRECTORY WITH TIME OF CREATION AS PART OF DIRECTORY NAME
 cd /home/adhikarisubir/test/basic_unix #this is the new line added, the rest is the same
 echo "The time is $(date +%H_%M_%S)"
 now=$(date +%H_%M_%S)
 echo $now
 echo $(pwd) 
 createdep=nowt_$now
 echo "$createdep"
 mkdir "$createdep"
 cd nowt_$now
 echo "Current directory is $(pwd)"
 echo "This is a text file which will contain the createtime" > Newtxt.txt
 sed -i "s/createtime/$(date '+%H:%M:%S')/g" Newtxt.txt
```

Another way to fix your problem is to change your `mkdir` command to use an absolute path. So your script would look like this:

```
#THIS CODE WILL CREATE A DIRECTORY WITH TIME OF CREATION AS PART OF DIRECTORY NAME
 echo "The time is $(date +%H_%M_%S)"
 now=$(date +%H_%M_%S)
 echo $now
 echo $(pwd) 
 #createdep=nowt_$now
 createdep=/home/adhikarisubir/test/basic_unix/nowt_$now  #createdep is now an absolute path
 echo "$createdep"
 mkdir "$createdep"
 #cd nowt_$now
 cd $createdep #this cd command now cds to $createdep
 echo "Current directory is $(pwd)"
 echo "This is a text file which will contain the createtime" > Newtxt.txt
 sed -i "s/createtime/$(date '+%H:%M:%S')/g" Newtxt.txt
```

It's better to always use absolute paths, so always use `/home/adhikarisubir/test/basic_unix` instead of saying `test/basic_unix`.

Note: I'm assuming your home directory is `/home/adhikarisubir`.

Comment: Thanks for your lucid and fluid answer. It is indeed very helpful.